# How to change the Contact details web part contact property using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, jquery

I am working in SharePoint 2016. I have a contact details webpart on one of the pages. Id like to change the Contact person information dynamically based on some other information.

[image: Edit Contact details WebPart]

This is how the webpart looks like in sharepoint designer

```
<WpNs0:ContactFieldControl runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{71ADC02E-ED0E-424D-BB6F-44C10CD731C2}" >
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Contact Details</Title>
  <FrameType>Default</FrameType>
  <Description>Displays details about a contact for this page or site.</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <ZoneID>FullPage</ZoneID>
  <PartOrder>6</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height>200px</Height>
  <Width>200px</Width>
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/wp_pers.gif</PartImageLarge>
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties>
  <ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID>
  <ID>g_71adc02e_ed0e_424d_bb6f_44c10cd731c2</ID>
  <CacheTimeout xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:CacheableWebPart">600</CacheTimeout>
  **<ContactLoginName xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:contactfieldcontrol">i:0#.w|domain\Contact.Name</ContactLoginName>**
</WebPart>
</WpNs0:ContactFieldControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could update web part property by JSOM.

Reference [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185010%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
var serverRelativeUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection/Default.aspx';

function updateWebPartTitle() {

    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);

    var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    this.collWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();

    clientContext.load(collWebPart);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.changeTitle), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function changeTitle() {

    if (!collWebPart.get_count()) {
        alert('No Web Parts on this page.');
    }

    var oWebPartDefinition = collWebPart.get_item(2);
    this.oWebPart = oWebPartDefinition.get_webPart();
    oWebPart.set_title('My New Web Part Title');

    oWebPartDefinition.saveWebPartChanges();

    clientContext.load(oWebPart, 'TitleUrl');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Title changed for Web Part: ' + this.oWebPart.get_titleUrl());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the link! but i couldn't change the contact name property.